# Are humans native to Avalonia?

Tags: strange-world

In the movie *Strange World*, we see that humans, along with a few other Earth-like species such as dogs, live in a relatively small valley surrounded by impassable mountains that is ultimately:

> on the back of an enormous turtle-like creature swimming on an oceanic planet.

While the humans are basically monocultural, they and the other Earth-like species that live aboveground exhibit essentially the same wide phenotypic diversity as evolved on Earth over a wide geographic area (i.e. they don't all look extremely similar). By contrast, the underground ecosystem consists wholly of utterly bizarre creatures that are part of

> a much larger superorganism, which more or less seems to be the only one of its kind on the planet,

and which have almost nothing in common with Earth species phenotypically.

Did humans and other Earth-like species evolve on Avalonia? Or did they come from elsewhere at some point and forget their origins?

Comment: They have spaceships, but only for moving around their environment

Comment: @Valorum - They are more airships. In fact, they cannot even go over the mountains, let alone to space. Although I am a little unclear on their technology: it seems as if they only need pando for propulsion, and that they have some type of anti-gravity magic. That is why Meridian's plane kept floating after stalling out and why the ground vehicles do not really touch the ground. However, if that were the case, why would they have trouble going over the mountains?

Comment: No help in *The Art of Strange World*